# Как получить DataFrame по условию < > текущей даты?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame:

```
index | date1               | date2              | text1 | text2
1     | 2021-01-20 19:17:02 |2021-01-22 19:15:02 | sadasd| asdasd
2     | 2021-01-22 15:12:02 |2021-01-23 19:15:02 | sadasd| asdasd
3     | 2021-01-23 13:17:02 |2021-01-24 19:15:02 | sadasd| asdasd
4     | 2021-01-24 18:17:02 |2021-01-25 19:15:02 | sadasd| asdasd
```

Как получить из данного фрейма только те строки, где дата меньше текущей на 3 дня?

Уже пробовал и загонять данные в строку, и выборкой с помощью `isin` - ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, с какими датами сравнивать сегодняшнюю, поэтому я сравниваю с обеими колонками с датами (либо одна, либо другая должны быть больше текущей даты на 3 дня). Разумеется, эти столбцы должны иметь тип `datetime64`. При ваших исходных данных:

```
                    date1               date2   text1   text2
index                                                        
1     2021-01-20 19:17:02 2021-01-22 19:15:02  sadasd  asdasd
2     2021-01-22 15:12:02 2021-01-23 19:15:02  sadasd  asdasd
3     2021-01-23 13:17:02 2021-01-24 19:15:02  sadasd  asdasd
4     2021-01-24 18:17:02 2021-01-25 19:15:02  sadasd  asdasd
```

можно сделать так:

```
today = pandas.to_datetime('today').normalize()
res = df[((today - df["date1"]).dt.days >= 3)|((today - df["date2"]).dt.days >= 3)]
```

тогда res будет:

```
                    date1               date2   text1   text2
index                                                        
1     2021-01-20 19:17:02 2021-01-22 19:15:02  sadasd  asdasd
```

Если вам нужно, чтобы обе колонки были на 3 дня старше текущей даты, смените оператор `|` на `&`.

Comment: И всё же лучше всегда писать `df.loc[` при выборке по условию, как рекомендуют разработчики `Pandas`

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
thresh = (pd.to_datetime("now") - pd.offsets.Day(3)).floor("D")
res = df.query("date1 < @thresh or date2 < @thresh")
```

результат:

```
In [38]: res
Out[38]: 
                date1               date2   text1   text2
1 2021-01-20 19:17:02 2021-01-22 19:15:02  sadasd  asdasd
```